# How to scan Ethereum blockchain fast using Python?

Tags: python, api, ethereum, blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I have a project in python that uses apis (like 1inch) to get price quotes from different tokens across the eth, bsc, etc. blockchains, but because i have big list of tokens to scan i'm getting rate limited with every api i use, and i was thinking about some solution.

I know you can get enterprise apis with a bigger limit but from what i've seen they only sell it to companies with some kind of application (although i've never contacted any web to ask for price).

I've tried switching between different apis but the result is always the same.

Is there any solution i could do ?. I thinked about using proxy rotation but don't know if that could work. Also i cant use web3 because of the response time, nor have a full node for every chain i work in.

If someone has more experiencie in this topic, would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You do

- Parallel API requests using multiple threads or processes: [Here is an example script](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps-concurrent.py)
- [You run your node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513)  next to your script to minimize the network latency and maximize bandwidth

[More tutorials how to read EVM data in scale](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/index.html) and then process it in Python.

Comment: Thank you man, appreciate your help!